# Подбор пароля C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть задание, а именно: реализовать алгоритм геренации пароля, используя словарь с комбинированием до трех слов, нечувствителен к замене пробелов символом "_" (нижнего подчеркивания). Не совсем понимаю условие задания. Нужно создать словарь, после чего комбинировать 3 слова. Но как сделать алгоритм нечувствительным к замене пробелов?

Comment: Приведите примеры входов и выходов и ваши попытки, если вы хотите решение в виде кода. Если хотите просто алгоритм, то поставьте соответствующую метку. Если непонятно условие, то спросите у того, кто его задал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но как сделать алгоритм нечувствительным к замене пробелов?

предварительно приведите строку к единому формату, например замените все пробелы на "_" или наоборот - все "_" на пробелы

> Не совсем понимаю условие задания

как я понимаю, есть словарь слов, надо выбрать случайно из словаря 3 слова и сформировать пароль как `слово1 слово2 слово3`

или же есть словарь внутри которого есть комбинации слов, причем разделитель между словами может быть как " ", так и "_"

В общем задание немного мутное или вы его не совсем правильно переписали :))
потому что

> используя словарь с комбинированием до трех слов, **нечувствителен** к
> замене пробелов символом "_"

уж как-то не по-русски звучит